# Sleep: Wake up at same time, or get more rest?

Tags: sleep

I've been hearing mixed advice on the topic of optimal sleep. Serge Faguet's [article on biohacking](https://hackernoon.com/im-32-and-spent-200k-on-biohacking-became-calmer-thinner-extroverted-healthier-happier-2a2e846ae113) suggests that waking up at the same time everyday, regardless of the time you sleep, is key to optimal rest.

On the flip side, [Dr. Matthew Walker on Joe Rogan Podcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwaWilO_Pig) 99% of us need 7-9 hours, always.

My question is, after a late night out, am I doing more to help my body by waking up at the same time everyday, or to sleep in?

Comment: Serge should go to sleep at 3 am and wake up at 6 every day for a month and see how he feels.

Comment: How is this related to fitness, it seems like just a general health question?

Comment: Everybody is different for many, many reasons and depending on many factors. If there was universally correct advice, you'd know about it.

Comment: @johnp do you know of a better place to ask a question like this?

Comment: @JanacMeena - Unfortunately no, not in the current form. It's close to being a good fit on medical science, but the scope there recently shifted to where they want more of a medical background to it. If you can edit it to be more of interest to medical professionals it can be migrated.

Comment: @DeeV The point of waking up always at the same time is that your circadian cycle adjusts to your life. If you stay late every day, then it's time to adjust your cycle accordingly and postpone it accordingly. According to https://www.sportsleepcoach.com/the-elite-coaching-team#the-book (and my previous experience, before reading the book) is that this works. You should try to maintain a constant wake up time and if you stay up late, then get in bed early sometime soon (e.g., the following night), rather than sleeping in. Not having constant waking time alters your circadian cycle.